# Changing the completion speed in company

Tags: company-mode

Is it possible to change the speed in which the `company` shows suggestions for completion? Per default it takes too long, so that it is still faster if one types the word himself than waiting for company suggestions.

Comment: It's a good idea to think of asking company-mode itself - see @DanJiadong's answer. The same technique applies generally. Start by `C-h f ____mode` or `M-x customize-group` etc. It is very easy to ask Emacs, once you get the habit of doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does `C-h f ____mode` to all modes?

Comment: Not every mode name ends in "-mode", but most do. But `C-h f` applies to all functions, whatever the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. M-x customize-group
2. Company
3. Company-idle-delay  (set this to a small value)